# Using all trackpad gestures via Apple Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, trackpad, multi-touch

How is possible send all trackpad gestures via Apple Remote Desktop.app (ARD)?

Some working, some not, especially don't works gestures:

- mission control (4 fingers up)
- exposee (4 fingers down)
- swiping left-right with 4 fingers - switching screens..

These gestures interpreted in my local machine, when i'm in windowed mode of ARD, and does nothing when i'm in fullscreen mode.

Is here any way use all gestures for example in full screen mode?

Comment: Do you mean "Screen Sharing"? I have nothing named Apple Remote Desktop.app. Mine is called "Screen Sharing.app". Anyway I haven't found an answer yet and wondering the same things... will come back if I find anything...
With Screen Sharing, if you put the remote desktop in full screen (actually this might be unnecessary), then hover to where the dock (the icon bar) is, it should open and you could manually click the Mission Control icon granted it's still there. To navigate...

Comment: @Jonny, Apple Remote Desktop is a non-free Apple application that allows an administrator to remotely administer a large number of Macs.  It is much more capable than the built-in screen sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to recognize all gestures and than send a keystroke to Remote Desktop which in turn will invoke the desired functionality on the remote machine.

BetterTouchTool can configure actions for gestures based on the current active application. This way you are able, for example, to map "three finger left" to the shortcut for "history back" which you can configure as the action of "three finger left swipe" for Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and here's how I fixed it: I went into System Preferences>>Trackpad then unclicked "Swipe Between Full Screen Apps", clicked "Swipe Between Pages", swiped a few times, then went back to Trackpad and reversed them (i.e. -- unclicked "Swipe Between Pages" and clicked "Swipe Between Full Screen Apps"). I don't know if all those steps were necessary, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your client computer is set up to recognize those gestures.   I would not expect them to be passed in windowed mode, but in full screen mode they should work if they are enabled on the client.  My guess is that they simply are not enabled on the client machine.

Comment: unfortunately, its enabled. (works, when i'm sitting at it)

Comment: Bummer.  Do the gestures get passed when you use regular screen sharing?