# Use external macbook trackpad as magic trackpad

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I have an old macbook pro (2017) which have a trackpad. Can I use that trackpad to control my new macbook, which I intend to elevate to relieve neck pain? Note that I already purchased a magic trackpad which works, but it feels looser than the one on my old macbook. Both macbooks are running the latest OS.

Comment: May be try[this](https://support.apple.com/guide/remote-desktop/apde0dd523e/mac)

Comment: @PtitXav I have tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't support certain gestures like 3-finger swipes.

Comment: Did you tried to disabled these gestures on the old Mac ?

Comment: @PtitXav I did not. I will try that.

Comment: I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49152/using-all-trackpad-gestures-via-apple-remote-desktop)